# AttributeError: 'New_Question' object has no attribute 'Tk'

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, attributeerror

I am trying to make a simple dialog box, and keep getting an AttributeError.
Here is the code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as font
import tkinter as tk
from Question import *
import pickle

class New_Question:
    #creating a root
    def __init__(self, category):
        self.cat = category
        self.qRoot = tkinter.Tk()

    def add_question(self):

        self.lblPrompt = self.Tk.Label(self.qRoot, text="Please enter a question for"+ self.cat)
        self.lblPromt.pack()
        self.entQuestion = self.Tk.Entry (self.qRoot)
        self.lbl.entQuestion.pack()

        self.lblAnswer = self.Tk.Label(self.qRoot, text="Please enter the answer:")
        self.lblAnswer.pack()
        self.entAnswer = self.Tk.Entry (self.qRoot )
        self.entAnswer.pack()

        self.q = question(self.qtext, self.qanswer)        
        self.qRoot.mainloop()
        return self.q
```

I just want it to bring up a tkinter window with the widgets.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you import a `Question` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error perfectly describes the problem. In your `__init__` function, you do not define any `self.Tk`. You need to use just `tk`.
You also import tkinter multiple times, which you should not do. Either remove the `import tkinter` or the `import tkinter as tk`.
More common is `from tkinter import *`, which allows you to leave out the `tkinter.` or `tk.`.
Here is an improved program (not tested):

```py
from tkinter import *
from Question import *
import pickle

class New_Question:
    #creating a root
    def __init__(self, question, answer, category):
        self.qRoot = Tk()
        self.lblPrompt = Label(self.qRoot, text="Please enter a question for "+ category)
        self.lblPrompt.pack()
        self.entQuestion = Entry(self.qRoot)
        self.entQuestion.pack()

        self.lblAnswer = Label(self.qRoot, text="Please enter the answer:")
        self.lblAnswer.pack()
        self.entAnswer = Entry (self.qRoot )
        self.entAnswer.pack()

        q = question(question, answer)
    def run():
        self.qRoot.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think the line `q = question(question, answer)` may raise exception if the passed argument `question` is not a callable object or a class.

Comment: Even though wildcard import may seem to be *more common*, it isn't something that's  recommended.

Comment: @acw1668 I can't figure out what `question` is, as it is not defined anywhere in the code.

Comment: @AST But for beginner projects, it makes it easier

Comment: `question` may be a class in `Question` module in OP design, but your solution is an argument of `__init__()`.

Comment: @acw1668 I know, the argument is supposed to be a string. Again, I don't know how to use `Question`.

Comment: Then why does your solution add the arguments `question` and `answer` to `__init__()` that OP code does not have?

Comment: In order to clean up the code. It needed values to come from *somewhere*.

Comment: @nerdguy thanks for the answer. I am new to coding and it was a great help. I imported "Question" because I have another script called "Question" and I forgot to take out the irrelevant imports. also your advise on importing tkinter is very helpful and i will use it going forward.